# how decrypt password from SecureCRT Session ini file

Tags: encryption, passwords, ini, secure-crt

Although official said it can't **[Recover Password from .ini file](https://forums.vandyke.com/showthread.php?t=3795)**, some Chinese guy [said it could](https://www.cnblogs.com/Yang34/p/14237114.html). But I can't make it work.

```
7.X, remove the first "u" in the head of password:
# python3  SecureCRTCipher.py dec hash

8.X, remove the three character such as "02:" at the begin of password:
# python3  SecureCRTCipher.py dec -v2 hash

suitable for lower than 7.X
#python3 SecureCRT-decryptpass.py 127.0.0.1.ini
```

They also said `Error: Failed to decrypt.` for me.

**SecureCRTCipher.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, Blowfish

class SecureCRTCrypto:

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initialize SecureCRTCrypto object.
        '''
        self.IV = b'\x00' * Blowfish.block_size
        self.Key1 = b'\x24\xA6\x3D\xDE\x5B\xD3\xB3\x82\x9C\x7E\x06\xF4\x08\x16\xAA\x07'
        self.Key2 = b'\x5F\xB0\x45\xA2\x94\x17\xD9\x16\xC6\xC6\xA2\xFF\x06\x41\x82\xB7'

    def Encrypt(self, Plaintext : str):
        '''
        Encrypt plaintext and return corresponding ciphertext.

        Args:
            Plaintext: A string that will be encrypted.

        Returns:
            Hexlified ciphertext string.
        '''
        plain_bytes = Plaintext.encode('utf-16-le')
        plain_bytes += b'\x00\x00'
        padded_plain_bytes = plain_bytes + os.urandom(Blowfish.block_size - len(plain_bytes) % Blowfish.block_size)

        cipher1 = Blowfish.new(self.Key1, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv = self.IV)
        cipher2 = Blowfish.new(self.Key2, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv = self.IV)
        return cipher1.encrypt(os.urandom(4) + cipher2.encrypt(padded_plain_bytes) + os.urandom(4)).hex()

    def Decrypt(self, Ciphertext : str):
        '''
        Decrypt ciphertext and return corresponding plaintext.

        Args:
            Ciphertext: A hex string that will be decrypted.

        Returns:
            Plaintext string.
        '''

        cipher1 = Blowfish.new(self.Key1, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv = self.IV)
        cipher2 = Blowfish.new(self.Key2, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv = self.IV)
        ciphered_bytes = bytes.fromhex(Ciphertext)
        if len(ciphered_bytes) <= 8:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Ciphertext.')
        
        padded_plain_bytes = cipher2.decrypt(cipher1.decrypt(ciphered_bytes)[4:-4])
        
        i = 0
        for i in range(0, len(padded_plain_bytes), 2):
            if padded_plain_bytes[i] == 0 and padded_plain_bytes[i + 1] == 0:
                break
        plain_bytes = padded_plain_bytes[0:i]

        try:
            return plain_bytes.decode('utf-16-le')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            raise(ValueError('Invalid Ciphertext.'))

class SecureCRTCryptoV2:

    def __init__(self, ConfigPassphrase : str = ''):
        '''
        Initialize SecureCRTCryptoV2 object.

        Args:
            ConfigPassphrase: The config passphrase that SecureCRT uses. Leave it empty if config passphrase is not set.
        '''
        self.IV = b'\x00' * AES.block_size
        self.Key = SHA256.new(ConfigPassphrase.encode('utf-8')).digest()

    def Encrypt(self, Plaintext : str):
        '''
        Encrypt plaintext and return corresponding ciphertext.

        Args:
            Plaintext: A string that will be encrypted.

        Returns:
            Hexlified ciphertext string.
        '''
        plain_bytes = Plaintext.encode('utf-8')
        if len(plain_bytes) > 0xffffffff:
            raise OverflowError('Plaintext is too long.')
        
        plain_bytes = \
            len(plain_bytes).to_bytes(4, 'little') + \
            plain_bytes + \
            SHA256.new(plain_bytes).digest()
        padded_plain_bytes = \
            plain_bytes + \
            os.urandom(AES.block_size - len(plain_bytes) % AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.Key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv = self.IV)
        return cipher.encrypt(padded_plain_bytes).hex()

    def Decrypt(self, Ciphertext : str):
        '''
        Decrypt ciphertext and return corresponding plaintext.

        Args:
            Ciphertext: A hex string that will be decrypted.

        Returns:
            Plaintext string.
        '''
        cipher = AES.new(self.Key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv = self.IV)
        padded_plain_bytes = cipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(Ciphertext))
        
        plain_bytes_length = int.from_bytes(padded_plain_bytes[0:4], 'little')
        plain_bytes = padded_plain_bytes[4:4 + plain_bytes_length]
        if len(plain_bytes) != plain_bytes_length:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Ciphertext.')

        plain_bytes_digest = padded_plain_bytes[4 + plain_bytes_length:4 + plain_bytes_length + SHA256.digest_size]
        if len(plain_bytes_digest) != SHA256.digest_size:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Ciphertext.')

        if SHA256.new(plain_bytes).digest() != plain_bytes_digest:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Ciphertext.')

        return plain_bytes.decode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    def Help():
        print('Usage:')
        print('    SecureCRTCipher.py <enc|dec> [-v2] [-p ConfigPassphrase] <plaintext|ciphertext>')
        print('')
        print('    <enc|dec>              "enc" for encryption, "dec" for decryption.')
        print('                           This parameter must be specified.')
        print('')
        print('    [-v2]                  Encrypt/Decrypt with "Password V2" algorithm.')
        print('                           This parameter is optional.')
        print('')
        print('    [-p ConfigPassphrase]  The config passphrase that SecureCRT uses.')
        print('                           This parameter is optional.')
        print('')
        print('    <plaintext|ciphertext> Plaintext string or ciphertext string.')
        print('                           NOTICE: Ciphertext string must be a hex string.')
        print('                           This parameter must be specified.')
        print('')
    
    def EncryptionRoutine(UseV2 : bool, ConfigPassphrase : str, Plaintext : str):
        try:
            if UseV2:
                print(SecureCRTCryptoV2(ConfigPassphrase).Encrypt(Plaintext))
            else:
                print(SecureCRTCrypto().Encrypt(Plaintext))
            return True
        except:
            print('Error: Failed to encrypt.')
            return False

    def DecryptionRoutine(UseV2 : bool, ConfigPassphrase : str, Ciphertext : str):
        try:
            if UseV2:
                print(SecureCRTCryptoV2(ConfigPassphrase).Decrypt(Ciphertext))
            else:
                print(SecureCRTCrypto().Decrypt(Ciphertext))
            return True
        except:
            print('Error: Failed to decrypt.')
            return False

    def Main(argc : int, argv : list):
        if 3 <= argc and argc <= 6:
            bUseV2 = False
            ConfigPassphrase = ''

            if argv[1].lower() == 'enc':
                bEncrypt = True
            elif argv[1].lower() == 'dec':
                bEncrypt = False
            else:
                Help()
                return -1
            
            i = 2
            while i < argc - 1:
                if argv[i].lower() == '-v2':
                    bUseV2 = True
                    i += 1
                elif argv[i].lower() == '-p' and i + 1 < argc - 1:
                    ConfigPassphrase = argv[i + 1]
                    i += 2
                else:
                    Help()
                    return -1

            if bUseV2 == False and len(ConfigPassphrase) != 0:
                print('Error: ConfigPassphrase is not supported if "-v2" is not specified')
                return -1

            if bEncrypt:
                return 0 if EncryptionRoutine(bUseV2, ConfigPassphrase, argv[-1]) else -1
            else:
                return 0 if DecryptionRoutine(bUseV2, ConfigPassphrase, argv[-1]) else -1
        else:
            Help()

    exit(Main(len(sys.argv), sys.argv))
```

**SecureCRT-decryptpass.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

# Decrypt SSHv2 passwords stored in VanDyke SecureCRT session files
# Can be found on Windows in:
#   %APPDATA%\VanDyke\Config\Sessions\sessionname.ini
# Tested with version 7.2.6 (build 606) for Windows
# Eloi Vanderbeken - Synacktiv
#  Decrypt SSHv2 passwords stored in VanDyke SecureCRT

# C:\>python SecureCRT-decryptpass.py -h
# usage: SecureCRT-decryptpass.py [-h] files [files ...]
#
#Tool to decrypt SSHv2 passwords in VanDyke Secure CRT session files
#
#positional arguments:
#  files       session file(s)
#
#optional arguments:
#  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
#
# C:\>python SecureCRT-decryptpass.py C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\VanDyke\Config\Sessions\192.168.0.1.ini
# C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\VanDyke\Config\Sessions\192.168.0.1.ini
# ssh -p 22 user@192.168.0.1 # 123456


from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
import argparse
import re

def decrypt(password) :
    c1 = Blowfish.new('5F B0 45 A2 94 17 D9 16 C6 C6 A2 FF 06 41 82 B7'.replace(' ','').decode('hex'), Blowfish.MODE_CBC, '\x00'*8)
    c2 = Blowfish.new('24 A6 3D DE 5B D3 B3 82 9C 7E 06 F4 08 16 AA 07'.replace(' ','').decode('hex'), Blowfish.MODE_CBC, '\x00'*8)
    padded = c1.decrypt(c2.decrypt(password.decode('hex'))[4:-4])
    p = ''
    while padded[:2] != '\x00\x00' :
        p += padded[:2]
        padded = padded[2:]
    return p.decode('UTF-16')

REGEX_HOSTNAME = re.compile(ur'S:"Hostname"=([^\r\n]*)')
REGEX_PASWORD = re.compile(ur'S:"Password"=u([0-9a-f]+)')
REGEX_PORT = re.compile(ur'D:"\[SSH2\] Port"=([0-9a-f]{8})')
REGEX_USERNAME = re.compile(ur'S:"Username"=([^\r\n]*)')

def hostname(x) :
    m = REGEX_HOSTNAME.search(x)
    if m :
        return m.group(1)
    return '???'

def password(x) :
    m = REGEX_PASWORD.search(x)
    if m :
        return decrypt(m.group(1))
    return '???'

def port(x) :
    m = REGEX_PORT.search(x)
    if m :
        return '-p %d '%(int(m.group(1), 16))
    return ''

def username(x) :
    m = REGEX_USERNAME.search(x)
    if m :
        return m.group(1) + '@'
    return ''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Tool to decrypt SSHv2 passwords in VanDyke Secure CRT session files')
parser.add_argument('files', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='+',
    help='session file(s)')

args = parser.parse_args()

for f in args.files :
    c = f.read().replace('\x00', '')
    print f.name
    print "ssh %s%s%s # %s"%(port(c), username(c), hostname(c), password(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error and eventually found out that the pycryptodome version was not compatible, I installed the latest version and replaced it with 3.8.2 and it worked fine:

```
pip install pycryptodome==3.8.2
```